# How to use Graphiql when graphql protected?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, graphiql

I have added the token to the properties file, yet unable to get the resource, and in request header there is no `authorization`, do I need to add any extra properties

```
graphiql:
    mapping: /graphiql
    endpoint:
      graphql: /graphql
      subscriptions: /subscriptions
    subscriptions:
      timeout: 30
      reconnect: false
    basePath: /
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer eyJraWQiOiJvMW5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Authentication header in JSON` format in the UI itself, refer the below image[image: Authentication]